# British SF TV Series, using a Black Hole for waste disposal

Tags: story-identification, tv

This British series was broadcast in approximately 2000-2003. It may have been a repeat of a previously aired series. It consisted of approximately four episodes.

In it, the UK government were using a black hole as a means of disposing of other countries’ radioactive waste. The method of disposal was kept a secret.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the (made-for-TV) movie [Doomwatch: Winter Angel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0225545/) (1999), based on the [Cult 1970s TV series of the same name](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065290/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1).

> Neil arrives on the scene and finds that something is going very wrong - and that the facilities staff are desperate for his help. **The research staff - whilst experimenting with particle physics - have created a tiny black hole - which they have contained in a magnetic field. They have also been feeding it all of the nuclear waste and other unwanted chemicals as the perfect clean solution, because nothing comes out of a black hole.** Unfortunately something went wrong and the magnetic containment is loosing it's grip on the black hole - hence the staff's worry and the effects of the blue radioactive glow. Neil surmises that the block hole has 'flipped' its magnetic polarity and the only way to bring it back under control is to tap the UK power grid and drag enough power to use the magnetic field to flip the black hole back again.

Answer (score 3):

*Doomwatch: Winter Angel*, 1999. [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0225545/) lists it as a movie, though; but it is the continuation of a [70s series of the same name](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065290/).

> Neil Tannahill a University lecturer is asked by the former head of Doomwatch (now very old and dying) to investigate the strange happenings at a remote nuclear facility. **Dangerous nuclear waste from around the world is being transported to this location for 'storage'.. and nobody is willing to say how this waste is being stored or disposed of**. A investigative reporter seeking a story see's the waste being loaded into the facility, plus an accidental spillage, and strange blue glow coming from the building. He is found and meets an untimely end by being handcuffed to his bicycle and dropped into the nearby lake - and drowned.
>
> Neil arrives on the scene and finds that something is going very wrong - and that the facilities staff are desperate for his help. **The research staff - whilst experimenting with particle physics - have created a tiny black hole -** which they have contained in a magnetic field. **They have also been feeding it all of the nuclear waste and other unwanted chemicals as the perfect clean solution, because nothing comes out of a black hole.**

Obviously, the black hole malfunctions, and Bad Things™ happen.

---

Found with the Google query `british series black hole waste disposal site:imdb.com/title`.